# WSO2 IS Add users to an existing group?

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have gone thorugh http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.in/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html .I could able to add users and groups.

Now i want to add more users to one existing group(Already created) by using SCIM .Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer a related question [1].

[1] [Create/Edit users with group or role in WSO2 IS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905233/create-edit-users-with-group-or-role-in-wso2-is)

Hope this helps.