# Create/Edit users with group or role in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

Is there any SCIM endpoints to add users with the groups? I already gone through the [article](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider), But i couldn't able to add user with group. Also i need to edit that user and update the group, Is there any SCIM endpoints for these two tasks ?

I tried with the following cURL command

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"gunasinghe","givenName":"hasinitg"},"userName":"hasinitg","password":"hasinitg","groups":[{"value":"a0612e1e-d8c7-47dd-b9ee-4218291945c8","display":"groupname"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current implementation it is not supported to add an user to an existing group, and this requirement is captured for the Identity Server road map.

Currently you can update the group with the newly added user, but the operation is PUT operation. Therefore it will replace the existing group with new data. Therefore you need to provide all the users at each PUT request with the new user.

Comment: 2018 - Is this operation supported now? I am using wso2is 5.6.0 and can't get myself to use patch.

Answer (score 2):

Patch operation is suitable for your requirement there you don't need to send entire user list in order to assign single user to a group. Patch operation will be supported with upcoming WSO2 IS releases very soon so keep in touch.

Comment: 2018 - Is this operation supported now? I am using wso2is 5.6.0 and can't get myself to use patch.